# Not able to figure out what is happening with the universal array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have created a program which takes an equation. from the user by asking about the degree of the equation. and then taking the co-efficients from the user and then forming the function which results into an equation. and then I have used the bisection method to solve it.

The program is::

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int stop=0,d,t[]={1};
float f(float x)
{
    int loop,loopa;
    float add=0.0,sum=0.0;
    for(;stop==0;)
    {
        int p ;
        cout << "Enter the degree of the poly. eq. (+ve integer)" << endl;
        cin >> d ;
        int *t = new int[d+1];
        cout << "The eq. will be in the form of ax^"<<d<<"+bx^"<<(d-1)<<" and so on ." ;
        p = 97 + d ;
        for(loop=d;loop>=0;loop--)
        {
            cout << "Enter the value of " << char(p-loop) << endl;
            cin >> t[loop];
            cout << "a="<<t[loop]<<endl;
        }
        stop=1; //ARRAY IS STILL THERE              WHY/////
    }       for(loop=0;loop<=d;loop++)      cout<<"out="<<t[loop]<<endl;
    //ARRAY IS GONE TILL NOW//
    cout<<"d="<<d<<endl;
    for(loopa=d;loopa>=0;loopa--)
    {
        cout<<"loopa="<<loopa<<"value="<<t[loopa]<<endl;
        add = t[loopa] * pow(x,loopa);
        sum=sum+add;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    float a , b , c , i , j ;
    A:
    cout << " Enter the starting point of interval " <<endl;
    cin >> a ;
    cout << " Enter the end point of interval " << endl;
    cin >> b ;
    cout << " Enter the number of iterations to be done . ( More the iterations , accurate is the result ) " << endl;
    cin >> i ;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(f(a)*f(b)>0)
        {
            cout << " The root of the above polynomial does not lies in the given interval . TRY AGAIN " << endl;
            goto A; 
        }
        else
        {
            c = a + b ;
            c = c / 2 ;
            if (f(a)*f(c)>0)    a = c ;
            else                b = c ;
            cout <<"hello"<< a << "aa \t" << b << "\t" << c << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Root = "<< c <<endl;
}
```

When the user gives the value of degree it creates an array of size one more than degree is created then there is a for loop which takes the value of co-efficients in that array . The problem is the value of the array stays intact till the first for loop . but as the control proceeds to the second loop ( see the two comments ) the value of the array is gone...I am using CodeLite ...guys help me?????

Comment: Why do you use caps?

Comment: PERHAPS YOU SHOULD TRY YELLING MORE.

Comment: All caps is considered yelling. Please consider using lowercase every now and then.

Comment: sorry for that..now will use only lowercase..

Comment: `int *t = new int[d+1];` creates a *different* array inside the loop, not associated with the global `t`. Like you have noticed, when the loop ends so does its scope and this new array goes away.

Comment: what can be done for that???any solutions...

Comment: @SatyamBansal - (a) delete the global declaration of `d` (`t[]={1};`), so you avoid confusion with two different variable with the same name; (b) declare `t` (`int * t = nullptr;`) before the `for`, so it can be used also after the `for`, and (c) initialize it (`t = new int[d+1];`) removing the initial `int *` (or you declare another variable and you have again the problem)

Comment: @max66 (a) cant initialize the array in the float f function,because it means the value of array becomes 0 every time the function is called , which would result in the eq. (b) same reason as (a) ...I want to take the array from the user only once and want to keep it till the end ....Suggest anything??

Comment: @SatyamBansal - I see... well, other suggestions: (a) if I understand correctly, the "Enter the..." part is executed only one time and `f()` a lot of times, so translate that part in `main()`; (b) avoid like the plague the use of global variables, so pass `t` and `d` (initialized in `main()` to `f()` as arguments.

Comment: @max66 thnx for that I will try it out... Can u plz suggest a site for learning c++...thnx mate..

Comment: @SatyamBansal - For learning? No, sorry: I've learned to much time ago and in that time there wasn't the web. But for reference I suggest [Cpp Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the array issue you just need to make a few small changes.

```
int stop=0,d,*t; // Declare an uninitialized pointer to int
float f(float x)
{
    int loop,loopa;
    float add=0.0,sum=0.0;
    for(;stop==0;)
    {
        int p ;
        cout << "Enter the degree of the poly. eq. (+ve integer)" << endl;
        cin >> d ;
        t = new int[d+1]; // Remove the int and asterix before t. You want to assign the new array to the pointer, not the value the pointer is pointing to.
        cout << "The eq. will be in the form of ax^"<<d<<"+bx^"<<(d-1)<<" and so on ." ;
        p = 97 + d ;
        for(loop=d;loop>=0;loop--)
        {
            cout << "Enter the value of " << char(p-loop) << endl;
            cin >> t[loop];
            cout << "a="<<t[loop]<<endl;
        }
        stop=1; //ARRAY IS STILL THERE              WHY/////
    }       for(loop=0;loop<=d;loop++)      cout<<"out="<<t[loop]<<endl;
    //ARRAY IS GONE TILL NOW//
    cout<<"d="<<d<<endl;
    for(loopa=d;loopa>=0;loopa--)
    {
        cout<<"loopa="<<loopa<<"value="<<t[loopa]<<endl;
        add = t[loopa] * pow(x,loopa);
        sum=sum+add;
    }
    delete[] t; // All new'ed things need to be deleted to not cause a leak. Delete it here since it is no longer needed.
    return sum;
}
```

Please note that even if this works, it is not advised to use raw pointers in C++. Better to use an `std::array<int>` or `std::vector<int>` so you don't have to take care of the allocating and deleting of memory.

**EDIT:** Accidentaly left the int in fron of t. Changed now.